# Using fscan() for a file, how can I do something with the values inside the file?

Tags: c

So if I have a file with several numbers, and I open the file using

```
fp = fopen (filename, "r");
```

So now I can read the contents of the file correct? How could I do something with the file. Like in this file there are numbers and I want to be able to add them up.

```
fscanf(fp)
```

would be the beginning of what is supposed to be correct? But I am not sure what to do beyond it. What code represents the items inside the file I am opening? If it is "x" then I want to add all the "x"'s up and then divide it by the total number of files there are.

How can I use the variables inside a file and do things with them?

---

Edited code:

```
if (fp != NULL)
{
     while (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &d) == 1)
     sum += d;
     mean = sum / total;

     printf ("The number of data values read from this file was %.0lf\n", total);
     printf ("\n%.2lf\n", mean);

     fclose(fp);
}
```

---

```
if (fp != NULL)
{
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (c != EOF)
        {
            if ((char)c == '\n')
            total++;
        }
    } while (feof(fp) == 0);
```

Comment: Is there any constraint that , must use `fscanf`. Or any read function you are expecting for ?

Comment: No I only used fscanf as an example of what to use, but anything would do as long as it gets the job done and it's in a similar library to fscanf?

Comment: This question seems to be "teach me about doing input in C" which is really too big a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Your `do { ... } while` loop would be written more idiomatically as: `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { if (c == '\n') total++; }` (assuming `total` was initialized to zero somewhere, and with the code spread over multiple lines). What you've got _is_ a more or less valid use of `feof()`; it is just an unnecessary one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only content in the file is valid numbers, this will work.  Actually, it will work until the first text that isn't a valid number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    char const *filename = "data.file";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        double d;
        while (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &d) == 1)
            sum += d;
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf("%g\n", sum);
    return(0);
}
```

As a general rule, if a function opens a file successfully, it should close it when it's finished.  In this example, the system would close the file anyway, but it is as well to get into good habits.  With a little more care and attention, you could distinguish between a format error (return value of 0 from `fscanf()`) and EOF or I/O error.

Comment: Hey so I used your code, and i added it to the original post, what i did but when I try to print out the sum or the mean i get a value of 0! In the same program I found the value of total and set the declarations and everything but I just copied the code that was relevant.

Comment: Since you've not shown how `total` is declared, initialized or set, it's impossible to guess what you're doing wrong.  One advantage of my code is that it is an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) which you can copy, compile and run (if you have a data file called `data.file`; mine contained three numbers, one per line: `3.1415
2.71828
1.61059`).  Maybe you need to increment `total` each time through the loop?  Maybe you're dividing by zero and getting an infinity instead of a number?  Who knows; we can't see your code.

Comment: I've edited the code to show I got the value for total. It is 39 in the case that I am using.

Comment: If you read the file once to count the number of lines, then you must remember to `rewind()` the file or `fseek()` back to the beginning so as to re-read it for the data (or vice versa; read the data, rewind, count lines). But a better strategy is to use `fgets()` to read lines (and you can count them as they come in) and then use `sscanf()` to scan the lines for one or more numbers (there are some tricks required to get multiple numbers, or you could use `strtod()` instead of `sscanf()`, or ...).  As it stands, without a rewind, you won't get any data on the second pass through the file.

Comment: Yessir! Rewind was the simple thing i was missing...thank you

Comment: Watch out for what happens if there are 3 numbers on a single line in the file.  `fscanf()` doesn't care; your total might be off, though.  Similarly if there are blank lines in the file; `fscanf()` still doesn't care; your total might be off again, though.  The behaviour might be fine; it depends on what you're computing.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example (not hardened) that adds the numbers read from a file...

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float sum = 0;
    float eachValue;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while (true)
    {
        int scanned = fscanf(fp, "%f\n", &eachValue);
        if (scanned == 1)
        {       
            sum += eachValue;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%f\n", sum);
}
```

For hardening, you should do things like deal with empty lines, validate there IS an arg[1] to be opened, deal with the cases where there's no file to be opened or some other error occurs during opening, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can have these many functions to read from a file in general.

```
int fgetc(FILE *stream);
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
int getc(FILE *stream);
int fscanf(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...);
size_t fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems,FILE *restrict stream);
```

depending upon your requirement use any one of this.

For example as you said , you have to add the numbers which are in the file.

So try reading from file with any of the above function into char array and then using delimiter (the character by which numbers are separated in file) parse the array into integer array or different numbers. Then it's easy to find the sum.

You should see [man strtod](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)

Also this [man strtok](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/)

Comment: Ok so if it's a floating point number what 'should' i use and how could i 'use' it to lets say, add the numbers in the file?

Comment: See my edit for int array , you can similarly do it for float also...using `strtok()` function on the delimiter or try using `strtod()` str to double function.

Comment: Try solving by yourself it's easy. First try to understand the different function related to file operations and work with small examples then try to solve the bigger ones.Directly asking the complete solution for this won't help you much.

Comment: I am currently trying to solve this. You said to put it into a char array, but can I just skip all that and in the fscanf() can I just put it all into a double array?

Comment: @albert : yes you have several ways to do it.

Comment: @Omkant what is "restrict" used in the fscanf().I have also read it on the fgets man page,searched on net but got no clue.